# How is that possible that SAS and R can test for main and interaction effects for the GEE if it has no likelihood?

Tags: regression, generalized-estimating-equations, deviance, effects

I was taught, that GEE, being not likelihood based, has no way to compare models. That we cannot assess the main and interaction effects the way we do with ordinary GLM, OLS, GLS, mixed models and so on.

We compare models to analyse the deviance, so we can determine which terms (effects) are statistically significant or not. This is also how the ordinary ANOVA, a special case of the analysis of deviance, performs. So far so good.

But how is that possible, that it's possible for GEE? All statistical packages I know, Stata, SAS, R, can do that. They say they assess the effects via Wald or "SAS score" (called "Generalized Score Statistics" - [Formula](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_genmod_details29.htm#statug.genmod.genmodgss)), but what does it mean actually? Is this about the estimated model parameters only (like the ordinary Wald statistics) but done "jointly"?

If not about deviance, based on the likelihood, the what is it about? The documentation of SAS (Type-3 analysis) and R mention multiple times that the models *ARE* compared  via Wald statistics. Is this very different from the analysis of deviance? Much worse?

Comment: I'm not clear on how generalized score statistics can work without having an assumed true model.  But most people using GEE use Wald statistics with standard errors derived from a robust covariance sandwich estimator, yielding approximate $\chi^2$ distributions.  In general I shy away from non-likelihood methods.  They are not as robust as they seem, requiring larger sample sizes to be accurate, and not being robust to missing data in the longitudinal case.

Comment: But how can I get a marginal model in case of a mixed model, for instance in R? They are, by nature, conditional to the random effects. I don't want to think in terms of random effects in my case, I only want to account for the within-cluster dependency. Ideally I would deal with the GLS estimation with unstructured covariance matrix, or other covariance structures + sandwich, but the residuals are far from normality. It's not also any typical GLM. I wanted GEE with gaussian cond. distr. + identity link. to bypass the limitation of the GLS. But then I need the assessments of main effects.

Comment: Simply put, I just want the GLS - only fixed effects + accounting for the within cluster dependency over time (unstructured or Toeplitz), but not restricted to even approximate normality of the residuals. I don't want any transformations, and I can hardly find any relevant GLM for it (gamma, beta?). All my colleagues use GEE for that, but I wanted to know how they could launch the type 2 (having no interaction) effects in n-way design (independent on the order of terms in the model). We have rarely missing data, usually very few with no clear pattern in them. GEE would fit my needs.

Comment: Then what you need is an ordinal longitudinal model.  See the last chapter of [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and hbiostat.org/proj/covid19.  Marginal models without random effects have a lot of advantages: fharrell.com/post/re

Comment: Ah, the ordinal logistic regression. I have 370 unique values, but maybe I could "bin" them like a histogram to obtain <200 categories. I found an explanation for the geeglm package in R: "The anova method allows either to produce a table of tests for sequentially adding terms to a model or to compare two nested models. The test statistic for testing the difference between model M1 and a submodel M2 is the Wald test statistic. If βis the parameter of model M1 and the submodel M2 is obtained from M1 by setting Cβ= 0 [...] https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/download/v015i02/81

Comment: Do you know maybe any R package, that can fit such ordinal logistic regression on longitudinal (4 time points, equally spaced for all subjects) data, where I can specify the unstructured covariance or Toeplitz (if the unstructured cannot fit) and without random effects?

Comment: Semiparametric models don't require any binning, especially if you use a computationally fast algorithm as in the R `rms` package `orm` function.  You can put the longitudinal measurements together using a Markov process as detailed [here](https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19).